# How to auto import wordpress contents from custom mysql database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to make my wordpress site get hes contents from another database and this is the database schema

database schema.

```
ID    title    contents    category    Fimage      time
1      XX      text          main      <html>      NOW()
2      YY      text          main      <html>      NOW()
```

Comment: 1) This is not a database schema, this is a table. 2) Where would you like to store the imported data, in a custom table or in a predefined  wordpress table? If the latter, then which one and what is the mapping of the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest was is to export database to csv file and then use one of csv import plugins.

Alternative way is to fetch data from the database as array and then run foreach loop and create a post for each row.